# Pointers and pass by reference c++

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In my main, I call the function compute_entropy and I give it a vector like this:
float entropy = h.compute_entropy(input_pic[0], & Symbol_table);

In Implementing the function itself (in h.cpp), I should not change the parameter it takes which is vector* prob.. how can I access the data of prob?

```
float compute_entropy(vector<Symbol>* prob)
{

    float ent = 0;
    vector<Symbol>* prob;


    for (int i = 0; i < prob.size(); i++)  //GIVES ERROR
    {
        ent +=    (prob.at(i).freq)   *   log2(  1 / (prob.at(i).freq)  );
    }
}
```

Comment: @MohitJain yes but prob.at() and prob.size() gives error since the declaration of prob is a pointer to the vector not the vector itself

Comment: Why did you declare `prob` locally. It is already an argument of function. You should ideally use `float compute_entropy(const vector<Symbol> &prob)`

Comment: @MohitJain while calling the function in the main.. how can I pass the parameter? compute_entropy(& Symbol_table) ??

Comment: Drop the `&`, just call `compute_entropy(Symbol_table);`. Check [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) for more information.

Comment: since the implementation of the function takes the parameter (pointer to vector) , I can not call it with the parameter of vector directly .. it gives an erroe @MohitJain

Comment: You should change it to reference. *pointers are evil*. Use container or array if you can. Or use reference. Still if doesn't work, prefer smart pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because type of `prob` is `Vector<Symbol> *`, you actually need to dereference it first before accessing member. It looks like `(*prob).at(i).freq`.

`*(A).B` can also be written as `A->B`, so instead of `(*prob).at(i).freq`, you can write `prob->at(i).freq`. (With similar argument `prob.size()` becomes `prob->size()`)

**Doing it in cleaner way**
Because you never change the contents of your vector you can make the argument constant.

```
float compute_entropy(const vector<Symbol>* prob)
```

Now as we know *pointers are evil*, let's replace pointer with a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

```
float compute_entropy(const vector<Symbol> &prob)
{

    float ent = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < prob.size(); i++)  //GIVES ERROR
    {
        ent +=    (prob.at(i).freq)   *   log2(  1 / (prob.at(i).freq)  );
    }
}
```

While calling this, if you were calling with vector, drop the `&` from the argument, and if you were calling with a vector pointer, dereference it with a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<Symbol>* prob;    
for (int i = 0; i < prob.size(); i++)  //GIVES ERROR
.....
```

Because prob is a pointer, you need to use the -> operator

```
for (int i = 0; i < prob->size(); i++)
```